# How to read Json.NET ISO 8601 format in Gson?

Tags: java, android, datetime, json.net, gson

In android How can I parse following DateTime ?

```
"2014-03-11T00:16:01.847" (iso 8061 format) Which is produced by NewtonSoft JsonConvert library
```

I have tried following format but did not succeed

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'"

"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD"
```

Comment: [8601 surely?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: I focused the title around *Gson* usage; if this is about parsing the/a DateTime *outside* of Gson, make sure to re-adjust the title (and remove the Gson tag).

Comment: @StuartLC yes it is. It is mentioned in their site as 'From Json.NET 4.5 and onwards dates are written using the ISO 8601 format by default and using this converter is unnecessary'  http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DatesInJSON.htm

Answer (score 1):

ISO 8601 format: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`

Comment: That is not ISO 8601 compliant. HH is 0 - 23. It will fail at midnight. There will be various other issues too. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: If the above is incorrect, can someone please edit it to be correct?